# Protractor End-To-End Testing using Ionic login with Firebase Facebook issue

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic-framework, authentication, protractor

I have tried to login with Facebook in Ionic using Firebase Facebook.
Using development process working fine. when tried with Protractor End-To-End facebook login not able to test.

Please watch below video link for better understanding.

```
FB-Login-With-Protractor : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghqjc7my4g0jxay/FB-Login-With-Protractor.mov?dl=0
```

Thanks

Lokesh Patel

Comment: can you share your html and protractor code??

Comment: Hi Danny,
Please find sample code below link : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojnnl2453j3ixth/ionic-tutorial-dinnerapp.zip?dl=0

Thanks